# Unable to get refresh token in asp.net web api project, using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, refresh-token

I develop an app that should run on server, when the app is loading its being automatically signing in and works fine.
however after an hour when the token is expired i can't use the app again,
it works via http get, and so i get a error response token expired.

I need to add to the Get function condition that checked if token is expired if so to request for refresh token,
however when im trying to do so i get the error
AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid

i tried to reproduce it via postman and the same error occur, can you guys please tell me what  i am doing wrong?

post https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id : value
client_secret: value
grant_type : refresh_token
refresh_token: the current access token i saved when app was initiated

*i also have resource but when i add it i get an error that it is not supported so i deleted it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by checking manually the expired flag and if expired to create new connection to the request.